# Wordpress Gatsby - How do i access ACF relationship content in graphql, or otherwise

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Using gatsby-source-wordpress I have a content type called 'student' which has a ACF relationship field that links to content type 'posts'. I want to show the related posts (title and other fields) on the student page.

On a student post i can get various fields of the related content, wordpress_id seems most useful (below is an example of the ACF relationship field on a 'student' set to show 'wordpress_id's:

```
{
   "node": {
      "acf": {
         "related_projects": [
            64,
            88,
            1
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

What i'd like to do is construct a graphQL query on the student page the selects all posts that match `enter code here`a set of wordpress_ids. I can see how to match a single id, but not multiple. Or can a single graphQL query be looped over on a page?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [ACF to REST API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/) on your WordPress site, then you can query related posts added via an *ACF Relationships* field.

Here is a GraphQL query example using a Flexible Content layout field called *Related Content* and a ACF relationship field called *Related Posts*:

```
{
  allWordpressPost {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        acf {
          content_post {
            __typename
            ... on WordPressAcf_related_content {
              related_posts {
                post_title
                post_content
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```